# Grails database migration plugin updateOnStart is not working

Tags: grails, groovy, database-migration

I need some help here. I have configured database migration plugin as the documentation says:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
```

This works fine when running 'grails run-app'. My database is migrated as expected, but how would I get this behavior when deploy my 'grails war' artifact?

I have tested it on tomcat, by manually copying the artifact to tomcat/webapps folder, but during deployment, hibernate complains about missing columns (the one that should have been created by the database migration plugin).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem ? I'm experiencing the same problems and it seems grails does not pick up `changelog.groovy`, I'm getting `changelog.groovy not found` I tried copying the changelog to various locations and I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that those two lines of code are available in production environment too?

This is an example of what I normally do in my applications:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
        // ... other useful development settings
    }
    test {
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.autoMigrateScripts = ['RunApp','TestApp']
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.forceAutoMigrate = true
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.dropOnStart = true
        if (loadTestData) {
            grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['testchangelog.groovy', 'testdata.groovy']
        } else {
            grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['testchangelog.groovy']
        // ... something test-related
        }
    }
    production {
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
        // ... production config settings
    }
}
```

Also, be sure to comment out relevant `dbCreate` entries in `DataSource.groovy` to avoid issues with migrations.

Comment: Hmm, I see. In my case I didn't put it in a specific environment, but I have added these two lines after the environment block, and therefore (I guess) it means that it would run everywhere.

How do you deploy your app? Do you execute a grails command to do it, or do you copy the app.war to tomcat (or other container)?

Comment: Yes, putting those lines out of an environment block should migrate your db as well. I suspect there are other settings in your config that may change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053160/3939511

I find that the default value for `grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation` at compile time is correct to have your change-logs included in the production war. I.e. I don't set/change this property in `Config.groovy` at compile time.

But in deployment I set `grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'migrations'`, as the change-logs end up in `WEB-INF/classes/migrations/` (as groovy scripts, not compiled classes).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you do a dbm-update that create the patches for you in the destination database.

Grabbed this from the Grails site.
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Update%20Scripts/dbm-update.html

dbm-update
Purpose

Updates a database to the current version.

Description

Runs all un-run changeSets from the changelog. Executes against the database configured in DataSource.groovy for the current environment (defaults to dev).

Usage:

Comment: I didn't understand how would this help me. I'm looking for a solution that does not involve running a grails command, I would like to be able to just deploy my war on tomcat, and then get my migration done during deployment...