# Grails database migration on deployed server

Tags: mysql, database, tomcat, grails, database-migration

Hi everyone I am encountering a problem/confusion with grails database migration plugin.

Resources used for studying-

1. Official Grails Database Migration Plugin documentation- http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/introduction.html
2. Database migration example- http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/manageDatabases.html

Now with the help of these I am very well able to migrate or do changes to my database on the local machine which has grails installed and working correctly.

The problem is that the production server is deployed online and I always upload my WAR file to deploy on apache tomcat. So it basically runs on JAVA so grails is not installed on the ubuntu machine. 
Now how will I migrate mysql database on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below config in your Config.groovy file. Migration will run during WAR deployment.

```
//===========================DATA MIGRATION============================
//Run changelog.groovy during application deployment on server?
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
//File used to run the db migration scripts
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy']
//Absolute path of changelog.groovy in the app base dir
grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogLocation = 'migrations'
//  the default schema to use when running auto-migrate on start
//grails.plugin.databasemigration. updateOnStartDefaultSchema ='schema' // You may not need this in MYSQL
//=====================================================================
```

Based on the above configuration, this is how your folder structure should be:

```
your-grails-project
      --migrations/
          --changelog.groovy
          --migration1.groovy
          --migration2.groovy
```

changelog.groovy

```
databaseChangeLog = { 
  include file: 'migration1.groovy'
  include file: 'migration2.groovy'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lalit. I already have these lines in my config.groovy. And I use 2 commands to generate changelog - First- `grails dbm-update` and second `grails dbm-gorm-diff changelog.groovy --add`. So do you mean I have to run these two commands on my local machine to generate the changelog and upload it on server and let it automatically handle changes?

Comment: Have edited my answer, please take a look. You need to have those files before you do a WAR generation.

Comment: What will happen on a web farm?  If I have 5 web servers, will the changelog script try to run 5 times?

Comment: @dudemonkey Does your 5 web servers connect to different database or they all connect to same database?

Comment: Same.  Actually they all connect to two different databases (both SQL based).  I don't have 5 yet but we're on our way.  I'm just trying to think through how to professionally manage database changes with the migration plugin.

Comment: @dudemonkey OK. so, liquibase will maintain a table in your database named: `databasechangelog`. This table will have all the information of changelog scripts executed on this database along with their checksums. So, if your changelog scripts are exactly same in all your web servers it should not be executed multiple times.